# keyboard hides in between while entering text into textfield

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard, uitapgesturerecognizer, first-responder

i am working on a login screen which contain a scroll view and on the scrollview there are two text fields with a login button.

scrollview used to adjust for the iphone 5 screen size. and i am using a "tab gesture" so the if any user is entering text in text field and want to hide keyboard then can click on anywhere on the screen to hide key board. function used for the tab gesture is

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

NSLog(@"login view");

UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTapGestureCaptured:)];
[self.scrollView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap]; }

- (void)singleTapGestureCaptured:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
[self.view endEditing:YES]; }
```

My problem is that when a user is entering text in the textfields using keyboard then in the middle of entering text keyboard detects the tab gesture and hides the keyboard in the middle.

**what i did to solve the issue:-** 
1.) i changed the  [self.view addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];

2.) i placed a view on the top of the screen with dimention (0,0,360,400) and apply the gesture to this view so that click on this view will hide keyboard but still when user types keyboard hide by calling gesture method

3.) i also used a button on the scrollview of half of screen size so taht user can click anywhere to hide the keybaord but**sill while typing even then keyboard hides y calling the ibaction method of button palced**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use This to hide the keyboard and show the keyboard:-

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField == username)
    {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];

    }
    if (textField == password)
    {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];

    }

    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField == username)
    {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification object:nil];
    }

    if (textField == password)
    {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];

    }
    return YES;
}


- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    CGSize keyboardSize = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    float newVerticalPosition = -keyboardSize.height + 100;

    [self moveFrameToVerticalPosition:newVerticalPosition forDuration:0.3f];
}


- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    CGFloat  kNavBarHeight =  self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height;
    [self moveFrameToVerticalPosition:kNavBarHeight forDuration:0.3f];
}

- (void)moveFrameToVerticalPosition:(float)position forDuration:(float)duration
{
    CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
    frame.origin.y = position;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
        self.view.frame = frame;
    }];
}
```

Comment: thanks for your responce ... i had implementede the same code provided by you ...but it didnt solved my problem...my issue here is that while typing keyboard hide automatically by calling gesture method.

Comment: comment that tapgesture method only this method which i have posted here use in your project it will help you...

Comment: okay ...thanks i will comment tab gesture....but after that click on the view will not dismiss keyboard ...i guess ?

Comment: on click of return key keyboard will hide

Comment: but i also want if user click rest of the screen keyboad should be dismiss.

Comment: You add this for hiding the keyboard when touching any where in view  tapper = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
              initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
    tapper.cancelsTouchesInView = TRUE;
- (void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *) sender
{
    [addItemScroll endEditing:YES];
}

Comment: i removed the scrollview and the tap gesture and implemeted the -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event----method and now its working perfect

Answer (score 3):

Remove `Tapgesture` And try this code , it will be helpful.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

Comment: i implemented the method it is working but it is giving black space on the top after returning

Comment: check the view which you placed for tap gesture and also check scrollview.

Answer (score 2):

I found the best solution for it. First you integrate the pod 'TPKeyboardAvoiding', '~>1.2.3' and just add the `TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView` Class. It will handle all.don't have to write extra code.

Answer (score 1):

try like this,

```
 -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

 [textField1 resignFirstResponder];
 [textField2 resignFirstResponder];
}
```

hope this will help :)

Comment: thanks for the response.... actually i am using a scrollview on the view....so touch method will not work untill i remove scrollview and touch was only be detected on the own view....

Comment: then add view on that scrollview and then add textfield to that view

Comment: as i made the whole functionality custom like move the textfield according to the screen size with scrollview... i just removed the tab gesture and scrollview...... i used @aayush ans to auto adjust the view when keyboard appear and use the touchesBegan method to handle the touch and hide the keyboard.... thanks again

Comment: you're welcome...:) and it is not tab gesture it is `tap gesture`!!! i found that your are using tab gesture everywhere so!!